# Can't access input field in POP UP UI selenium. StaleElementReferenceException after element found clickable

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, staleelementreferenceexception

I am trying to access an input field in a pop up UI(`Aantal KvK uittreksels`). Right now I am trying this code:

```
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(.,'custom_field_387439')]")))
element.send_keys("testing")
```

That results in this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

This is the webview + Google Elements:
[image]

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StaleElementReferenceException` appearing after applying `WebDriverWait` `element_to_be_clickable` `expected_conditions` means that the page you are working on is built with not Selenium friendly dynamic DOM technique. The page rendering is performed so that on some step the desired physical element is already exists and even appears clickable i.e. defined as fully rendered, but after that the page rendering is still continues so the previously collected by Selenium web element (actually a pointer to the physical element on the DOM) reference no more pointing to that physical element, since previously created physical element no more exists, new physical element is now created.
To overcome this we can create special method attempting to click element in a loop. Something like this:

```py
def click_element(locator):
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).click()
            break
        except:
            pass
```

Send keys can be done in exactly the same way:

```py
def send_keys_in_loop(locator, value):
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).send_keys(value)
            break
        except:
            pass
```

You can use these methods in the following way:

```py
click_element((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(.,'custom_field_387439')]"))
send_keys_in_loop((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(.,'custom_field_387439')]"),"testing")
```

Please pay attention on the fact that the `locator` parameter here is a tuple so that I use double parenthesis when calling `click_element` and `click_element` methods while inside those methods implementation you can see only single parenthesis inside the `element_to_be_clickable(locator)` expression.

Comment: I guess this should work. Depending on the actual project structure possibly `driver` should be passed as a parameter into such methods.

Comment: Thanks, i tried this, but nothing happens, no error but also no input. i also tried: `ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(.,'custom_field_387439')]")))
ele.send_keys("test")` but that gave me a timeout.

Comment: Awesome! i fixed the issue by adding a new selector(id): `def send_keys_in_loop(locator, value):
    for i in range(5):
        try:
            wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(locator)).send_keys(value)
            break
        except:
            pass

send_keys_in_loop((By.XPATH, "//input[contains(@id,'custom_field_387439')]"),"testing")`  Thanks allot again!